# Overflow variable by addition

Tags: c++

I was doing a Leetcode question.
I have understood the logic but there was a small doubt on interger value overflow

Here is my code:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) 
{
   int size;
   vector<vector<int>>re;
   vector<int> a;
   vector<int> b;
   a.push_back(1);
   re.push_back(a);
   numRows--;
   while(numRows--)
   {
       b.push_back(1);
       size=a.size();
       size++;
       for(int i=1;i<size-1;i++)
       {
           b.push_back(a[i]+a[i-1]); //  <------ It is showing interger overflow at this 
       }
       b.push_back(1);
       re.push_back(b);
       a=b;
       b.clear();
   }
   return re;
}
```

here is the code that run perfectly fine :

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
    vector<vector<int>> r(numRows);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        r[i].resize(i + 1);
        r[i][0] = r[i][i] = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            r[i][j] = r[i - 1][j - 1] + r[i - 1][j]; //  <- Doing same addition but not facing any interger overflow issue ?
        }
    }
    
    return r;
}
```

I want to know the above code is not facing integer overflow on the same test cases.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Using `numRows == 0` will cause an infinite loop. However, one thing that may be a problem (and compiler should warn you about) is using `int` for vector sizes. Change `size` and the `i` in the `for` loop to `size_t` types.

Comment: Link to Leetcode problem would be very helpful, explaining what this code suppose to do.

Comment: What test cases?   If you don't provide those, you are forcing people to guess what test cases are encountering problems.   A value of `numRows` which is non-positive will eventually decrement it enough to cause overflow (going past largest negative value) and that will cause undefined behaviour.   Also, `a.size()` is `1` on the first loop iteration, so the loop will run from `1` to `1` - which means `a[i] + a[i-1]` will add `a[1]` and `a[0]`, which causes undefined behaviour since only `a[0]` exists.